# Compile Grails GSP at build-time for use as a static asset by Asset Plugin

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, gsp

Is it possible to compile a Grails GSP at build-time into a static file (of whatever type I want; e.g., possibly html, js, css, etc.)?

I want to treat the result as an asset, so that it could be included in an Asset Pipeline static bundle served by a static server rather than served by my Grails server.

The GSP would only depend on Grails config settings known at build-time, not on runtime logic, so it would be safe to deploy the generated file to a static server rather than serving it from my Grails server.

If this is possible, would the Grails build issue an error if one of these build-time-compiled GSPs accidentally included code that had to run in a Grails server (e.g., if it accessed a request object)?  Or would it silently ignore such errors?

If this isn't possible with GSP, is there some other technology that I can use to generate files from my Grails config at build-time?

Comment: While not precisely what you are trying to do, there is a plugin out there that lets you use the Groovy Template engine for assets.
https://github.com/tednaleid/groovy-template-grails-asset-pipeline

I have not used it, though. I've had similar needs (for example, to use the createLink gsp tag within a javascript file for an AJAX url), but haven't yet found a solution that I entirely like.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I probably won't have time to look into this soon (other work to do), but I'll post here later if I find / make anything useful.